# Showing that a system of equation is inconsistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When working out this system of equations, I've found that there are no solutions.

Is there any way from the start you can Identify that this system of equations has no solutions?

$2x + y − z + u = 1$

$3x − 2y + 2z − 3u = 2$

$5x + y − z + 2u = −1$

$2x − y + z − 3u = 4$

Comment: You just create the augmented matrix and row reduce to Row reduced echelon form, inconsistent systems have a non zero entry in the augmented column with zeros in the non augmented row before it

Comment: So is there no way of looking at it and determining that it is inconsistent?

Comment: Not that I know of, usually having more or less equations than variables is only an indication of non-uniqueness of the solution. Some special cases might be easy like if two equations are the same but with different right hand sides

Comment: Just looking at it, the z coefficient equals the negative of the y coefficient in all 4 equations.  This means that it will be impossible to isolate y and z by elementary row operations.  The equations are linearly dependent.  This means that there will not be a unique solution, but is not sufficient information to know whether there are infinitely many or no solutions.

Comment: His however might help guide you http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/vcalc/system/system.html

Answer (score 4):

The only way is to form the matrix of the system and do row reductions: $$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc|c}
      2&1&-1&1&1\\3&-2&2&-3&2\\5&1&-1&2&-1\\2&-1&1&-3&4
          \end{array}
\right] $$

For fewer variables, sometimes you can try to graph them out to see whether the lines are intersecting, same, or parallel, and from there you can decide if the system if consistent. But in this case where there are four variables, obtaining the row-echelon form would probably be the fastest way.

Comment: That is an excellent way, but it is certainly not the *only* way. You do not need to use matrices at all.